# Is there a pass by reference setting in WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: ejb, websphere-liberty

Is there a way to configure WebSphere Liberty to use call-by-reference for calls to remote EJBs inside the same JVM? In WebSphere traditional this is possible by choosing "Pass by reference" under "ORB service" in the console, and both WebLogic and WildFly have similar settings, but I haven't been able to find anything similar in the Liberty configuration documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. If you want call by reference semantics you should use a local interface to the EJB rather than a remote one.